# jQuery How to prevent form submit in this case

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I have this image upload form that I check on 'change' for file type and file size.

If a file is above a certain size or if its not an image, it'll alert the user. Problem I'm having is, how do I prevent the form from being submitted when this is the case. If I were to click the upload button the file submits. Actually it should not until the file is a certain size and type.

Can you help me set this right? I've tried, but I just cannot figure out where and what to do.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="">
        <input type="file" name="file" class="file"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
    </form>
```

Script (this is done using the jquery form plugin)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$(':file').change(function(){
            var file = this.files[0];
            name = file.name;
            size = file.size;
            type = file.type;

            if(file.name.length < 1) {

            }
            else if(file.size > 1000000) {
                alert("File is to big");
            }
            else if(file.type != 'image/png' && file.type != 'image/jpg' && !file.type != 'image/gif' && file.type != 'image/jpeg' ) {
                alert("File doesnt match png, jpg or gif");
            }
            else { 

            $(':submit').click(function(){
                var bar = $('.bar');
                var percent = $('.percent');
                var status = $('#status');

                $('form').ajaxForm({
                    url:"upload_file.php",
                    type:"post",
                    dataType:"json",
                    target:"#status",

                    beforeSend: function() {
                        status.empty();
                        var percentVal = '0%';
                        bar.width(percentVal)
                        percent.html(percentVal);
                    },
                    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                        bar.width(percentVal)
                        percent.html(percentVal);
                    },
                    complete: function(xhr) {
                        status.html(xhr.responseText);
                        $("#status").html("HIIII Gais");

                    }
                });

                });
}
});             
    });       
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you assigning the click event inside the change event.. instead assign the click event out side and then trigger it from the inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a variable outside the two functions and set it to true if its valid.. If it's valid then send a request , otherwise prevent default..

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var isValid = false;

    $(':file').change(function() {

        isValid = false;

        var file = this.files[0];
        name = file.name;
        size = file.size;
        type = file.type;

        if (file.name.length < 1) {

        } else if (file.size > 1000000) {
            alert("File is to big");
        } else if (file.type != 'image/png' && file.type != 'image/jpg' && !file.type != 'image/gif' && file.type != 'image/jpeg') {
            alert("File doesnt match png, jpg or gif");
        } else {
            isValid = true;

        }
    });

    $(':submit').click(function(e) {
        if (!isValid) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            var bar = $('.bar');
            var percent = $('.percent');
            var status = $('#status');

            $('form').ajaxForm({
                url: "upload_file.php",
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                target: "#status",

                beforeSend: function() {
                    status.empty();
                    var percentVal = '0%';
                    bar.width(percentVal)
                    percent.html(percentVal);
                },
                uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                    bar.width(percentVal)
                    percent.html(percentVal);
                },
                complete: function(xhr) {
                    status.html(xhr.responseText);
                    $("#status").html("HIIII Gais");

                }
            });
        }

    });
});​
```

Comment: You need to take into account that if the user selects one valid file but changes it to an invalid one before form submit, he will get alerted but `isValid` will remain `true` (since it was only initialized on DOMReady). So you might want to add `isValid = false;` at the beginning of the change event handler function.

Comment: @spider .. I set that the false initially , to handle the condition wherein the user might click the submit button without changing the file ..

Comment: @spider You are right. Select a valid file first and don't submit it. Then select and Invalid file and it get submitted. So where where exactly should this var isValid = false; go. Before which part or line. Honestly, I'm -1 with javascript.

Comment: @Norman .. I have added that into the code.. Right after the change event

Comment: @Sushanth-- I did the same thing. It still lets an invalid file tru after you select a valid one.

Comment: @Sushanth-- Ok. My Bad. It works. Thanks to both of you for helping me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get more than the filename from the file input element with javascript. You need to do the filesize, mime type, etc checks on the server side.

Comment: File.size and file.type actually work. Its the "preventing the user from submitting the form" that I'm stuck with.

Comment: Then just use jQuery's `event.preventDefault();` or `return false;`